# O que torna explode() melhor que split() em php?

Tags: php

Sei que a função `split` está obsoleta e há a função `explode` que a substitui, mas o que exatamente faz com que a `explode` seja melhor?

Comment: Explode não substitui(u) a _split_, até porque as duas são completamente diferentes em termos de operação. A função explode limita-se a dividir _string_ por _string_, ou ainda quando especificado um termo, ela trabalha à partir daí, enquanto a função _split_ usa(va) como base expressões regulares para repartir as _strings_. Ainda assim as diferenças são bastante óbvias e explícitas no manual do _php_, e também pelo facto de não saber se já existe uma resposta a esta pergunta, deixarei apenas este comentário.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Split é uma função das versões mais antigas do PHP, que fazia algo similar ao `explode`, tendo como diferença a utilização de expressões regulares.

Não me lembro a referência agora, mas essa função era seis vezes mais lenta do que `explode`.

Agora, temos que levar em consideração que ambas são parecidas, não idênticas. Explode trabalha com divisão através de delimitador indicado por `string`, já `split`, expressão regular.

Vale lembrar que `explode` não veio substituir a função `split`, e sim a função `preg_split`.

O uso de `preg_split` é encorajado no lugar de `split`

Veja um exemplo:

```
$parts = preg_split('/,|\./', 'teste.teste,teste');
```

Isso gera:

> ['teste', 'teste', 'teste']

E respondendo diretamente a pergunta *O que explode faz melhor do que split*?

A não utilização de expressão regular pode significar muito. Nem sempre quando precisamos dividir uma string para um `array` precisamos de uma expressão regular. Daí a idéia de se utilizar `explode` ao invés de `split`.

E mesmo que `preg_split` seja a substituta de `split`, em casos onde não se analisa a string rigorosamente para divisão, é encorajado usar `explode` ao invés.

Comment: Outro ponto interessante é que eu pensava que a função `join` existe em PHP (tenho impressão que quiseram imitar o javascript). Porém, esta é sinônimo para `implode`. Toda função em PHP que é sinônimo **não deve ser usada**, pois que serão removidas no futuro.

Comment: Obs.: A Regex `/,|./` tem o intuito correto mas esta errada, o "." representa qualquer coisa, assim o `preg_split` ira explodir a `string` de forma erronia, alterar para `/,|\./` ou `/[,\.]/`, pois "\." é o literal.

Comment: Obrigado Senhor @GuilhermeLautert