# Pegar numeros separados por ponto e virgula em PHP

Tags: php

Ola, tenho uma sequencia de numeros em uma string, exemplo: 1;2;3;4;5;6.
Gostaria de pegar cada numero e guarda-los em um array de inteiros em PHP.
Alguem tem uma sugestão?

Comment: Procura por split em php... Agora n tenho como postar uma resposta, mas qnd possível se ainda nao estiver resolvido tento te ajudar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basta utilizar a função nativa [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.explode.php):

```
array explode ( string $delimiter , string $string [, int $limit ] )
```

O primeiro parâmetro é o delimitador, ou seja, a expressão que você quer usar como referência para dividir seu texto e o segundo parâmetro é o texto em si. O terceiro parâmetro é opcional e, se definido, limita o número de separações feitas.

Para o seu exemplo:

```
$lista = explode(";", "1;2;3;4;5;6");
print_r($lista);
```

O resultado é:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 4
    [4] => 5
    [5] => 6
)
```

**Perguntas relacionadas:**

[O que torna explode() melhor que split() em php?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/95744/o-que-torna-explode-melhor-que-split-em-php)

Answer (score 1):

O comando para isso é o `explode` conforme dito acima de forma muito clara.

Segue o link para referencia no site do PHP:
http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.explode.php

E um outro exemplo de uso um pouco mais detalhado:

```
<?php

//string que recebe os números
$_string = "1;2;3;4;5;6";<br />
//O explode define qual vai ser o caractere a ser usado na divisão da string e a variável $converte_array recebe as substrings resultantes desta divisão.  
$converte_array = explode(";",$_string );
//como exibir esses resultados:
echo $converte_array[0]; //retorna 1
echo $converte_array[1]; //retorna 2
echo $converte_array[2]; //retorna 3
echo $converte_array[3]; //retorna 4
echo $converte_array[4]; //retorna 5
echo $converte_array[5]; //retorna 6
// sem se esquecer que arrays em php assim como em outras linguagens se iniciam em 0 e não em 1
```